# How to deserialize json Object in Object with jackson(Java)?

Tags: java, json, jackson

How to deserialize json Object (`Offer` object present in `current` field in my case) in Object with jackson(Java)?

input String:

```
message.getMessage();
```

{"header":"OFFER","message":"{\"author\":\"Peter Smith\",\"previous\":null,\"current\":{\"id\":\"eOUQieQdvB\",\"authorUserId\":\"foo\"}}"}

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
PushEventMessage<PushEvent<Offer>> pushEventMessage = mapper.readValue(message.getMessage(), PushEventMessage.class);
pushEventMessage.getMessage();
```

{"author":"Peter Smith","previous":null,"current":{"id":"eOUQieQdvB","authorUserId":"foo"}}

```
PushEvent<Offer> pushEvent = mapper.readValue(pushEventMessage.getMessage(), PushEvent.class);
pushEvent.getAuthor(); // is OK and contain "Peter Smith"

pushEvent.getCurrent() // is KO and contain {id=eOUQieQdvB, authorUserId=foo}
```

I want deserialize:

```
Offer offer= mapper.readValue(pushEvent.getCurrent() + "", Offer.class);
```

**My error is:**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{id=eOUQieQdvB, authorUserId=foo,
```

**EDIT 1**, I add `PushEvent<T>` class.

```
import lombok.*;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class PushEvent<T> {
    String author;
    T previous;
    T current;
    String error;
}
```

**EDIT 2**, I try this but the result is the same

```
PushEvent<Offer> pushEvent = mapper.readValue(pushEventMessage.getMessage().replaceAll("\\\"", "\""), PushEvent.class);
```

**I take the solution of @Smutje and this fix the 1st problem.**!!

**EDIT 3**, I have a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` in `Offer` object.

{"author":"Peter Smith","previous":null,"current":{"id":"00Yno9WwsL","authorUserId":"foo","createdAt":{"offset":{"totalSeconds":0,"id":"Z","rules":{"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[],"fixedOffset":true}},"zone":{"id":"UTC","rules":{"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[],"fixedOffset":true}},"dayOfMonth":11,"dayOfWeek":"SUNDAY","dayOfYear":42,"month":"FEBRUARY","year":2018,"hour":1,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"monthValue":2,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}}}

I have this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":"00Yno9WwsL","authorUserId":"foo", ....."createdAt":{"offset":{"totalSeconds":0,...
```

**EDIT 4**, I add `Offer` class.

```
@Slf4j
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Offer {

    @Id
    protected String id;

    protected String authorUserId;

    protected ZonedDateTime createdAt;

}
```

Comment: What return type does `pushEvent.getCurrent()` have?

Comment: why not having another POJO? cannot deserialize to `Offer` because it don't have `id`, and remaining fields, can you show `Offer` class?

Comment: @Smutje, LinkedHashMap in my case because all double-quote as revoved (
I do not know why?) I wanted an object "Offer".

Comment: Please add your "PushEvent" class.

Comment: @Smutje, I edited my question with `PushEvent<T>` class.

Comment: OK, and this is being parsed correctly? Good to know!
Usually Jackson cringes hard when having to deserialize generic types or inheritance hierarchies so it might be simpler to create a `PushEvent` object manually out of JsonNode.

Comment: @second, yes I do a wrong copy/paste for stackoverflow (in my real case, the `Offer` object is bigger). I edit the question with fix this problem.

Comment: show the `Offer class @sgrillon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the inability of many mapping frameworks to properly deserialize objects using generics or inheritance hierarchies the following is ugly but should be possible

```
PushEvent<Offer> pushEvent = mapper.readValue(pushEventMessage.getMessage(), PushEvent.class);
String serializedOffer = mapper.writeValueAsString(pushEventMessage.getCurrent());
Offer offer = mapper.readValue(serializedOffer, Offer.class);
pushEvent.setCurrent(offer);
```

Explanation: Jackson deserializes your inner object not as `Offer` as you stated it but rather as a `LinkedHashMap` which is being serialized as a JSON object again before reading the JSON object as actual `Offer`.

Your attempt to read the `LinkedHashMap` into a `Offer` failed because you (implicitely) used the `toString` representation of `LinkedHashMap` to parse which does *not* produce valid JSON.

**EDIT 4 answer:**, if Object contain a `ZonedDateTime`. Use this when write and read:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat());
```

Comment: thank you, I have one last question. My Offer object contains a ZonedDateTime

Comment: \"createdAt\":{\"offset\":{\"totalSeconds\":0,\"id\":\"Z\",\"rules\":{\"transitionRules\":[],\"transitions\":[],\"fixedOffset\":true}},\"zone\":{\"id\":\"UTC\",\"rules\":{\"transitionRules\":[],\"transitions\":[],\"fixedOffset\":true}},\"dayOfMonth\":11,\"dayOfWeek\":\"SUNDAY\",\"dayOfYear\":42,\"month\":\"FEBRUARY\",\"year\":2018,\"hour\":1,\"minute\":0,\"nano\":0,\"second\":0,\"monthValue\":2,\"chronology\":{\"id\":\"ISO\",\"calendarType\":\"iso8601\"}}

Comment: Please extend your question, comments are not good for long lines of code

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":"00Yno9WwsL","authorUserId":"foo", ....."createdAt":{"offset":{"totalSeconds":0,...

Comment: To make it short: Ignore the field on deserialization and fill it manually reverse to your serialization strategy.

Answer (score -1):

The error message tells you what the problem is: "was expecting double-quote to start field name".

From a brief inspection, your code to read the json string looks correct, so make sure you are providing it with valid data.

Hint: you can generate known good data by simply serialising a demo object with:

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(demoObject);
```

You can then try to run your code with that string, and this will tell you if your input is valid or not.